# Functions from finite field to itself

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have read somewhere that for $F$ a finite field with $q$ elements, any function $F\rightarrow F$ is a polynomial function.

If $A=\{f:F\rightarrow F\}$ is the set of such functions and $B=\{\text{polynomials of degree}\le q-1\}$. Then $|A|$, $|B|$ have both $q^q$ elements.

**EDIT:** Then it's enough to show that there is an injective map from $B\rightarrow A$ which is immediate from the definition of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: If you have a map between two finite sets of the same size, and you want to show that this map is bijective, it is enough to prove that this map is injective. So you need to show that the map $B \to A$ which maps every polynomial to its respective function is injective. What do you know about polynomials?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Yes, only need the bijection. Thanks. Ok I have done that.

Answer (score 2):

One can find the coefficients of the polynomial $c_0+c_1t\ldots+c_{q-1}t^{q-1}$ equal to a given function $f:\mathbb{F}\rightarrow\mathbb{F}$ by solving the system $c_0+c_1 e+\ldots+c_{q-1}e^{q-1}=f(e)$ with $e$ running over $\mathbb{F}$. This is a system with $|\mathbb{F}|$ equations and $|\mathbb{F}|$ variables; the coefficients form a Vandermonde matrix, so a solution exists regardless of the values of $f$.